# Solve Time Limit Exceeded for list<int> in c++

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

The input begins with an integer \$q, 1 \leq q \leq 10^5\$, the number of queries. The next \$q\$ lines each gives a query. A query is \$\text{"a x"},  1 \leq x \leq 10^9\$

Print the result of each query on a single line. For each a query, print the last integer in the queue that is smaller than \$x\$. If there is no such integer, print \$-1\$.

Why my code could cause time limit exceeded?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

list<int> mylist;

int searchSmall(){
    list<int>::const_iterator i;
    for (i = mylist.begin(); i != mylist.end(); ++i){
        if(*i < mylist.front()){
            return *i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main (){
  int n;
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin >> n;
  while(n--){
      char e;
      cin >> e;
      if(e == 'a'){
          int q;
          cin >> q;
          mylist.push_front(q);
          cout << searchSmall() << endl;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please complete the problem statement, make it a *block quote*, and provide a hyperlink to its source. Your question is at the verge of being [off topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for not asking for a review, but the reason for TLE.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `using namespace std;`

You don't say what platform you're on or what time limit is being exceeded, but for performance, replace

```
#include <list>
list<int> mylist;
```

with

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> mylist;
```

and

```
mylist.push_front(q);
```

with

```
mylist.push_back(q);
```

and re-measure. This will be much faster

Comment: and, as Roland says, use '\n' instead of `std::endl`

Comment: Martin York - please don’t edit my answer to add your advice in my name. Add your own comments and attribute them appropriately

Answer (score 3):

This is a classical range query problem. You get a TLE most likely because you're using a linear time data structure. Based on the input size (worst case) you'll have to spend C*10^5 * 10^10 cycles processing which would probably lead to a TLE in most OJs. Consider using a `priority_queue` or a binary tree to order your data for \$\log(n)\$ access. Namely, you should try changing your `list` to a `priority_queue` and then perform insertion and lookup using the priority queue/tree. This gives you a worst-case time complexity of \$O(n \log n)\$.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `std::endl`. Use a simple `"\n"` instead. Investigate the reasons yourself.

If the above does not help, measure the performance on your local computer and provide more details than a simple "it is too slow".